# Are the norms $\Vert f\Vert_1=\Vert f\Vert _\infty+\Vert f'\Vert _\infty$ and $\Vert f\Vert _2=\vert f(a)\vert +\Vert f'\Vert _\infty$ equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

We have the norms $\Vert f\Vert_1=\Vert f\Vert _\infty+\Vert f'\Vert _\infty$ and $\Vert f\Vert _2=\vert f(a)\vert +\Vert f'\Vert _\infty$ where $f\in C^1[a,b]$. Are they equivalent and how shoud I prove/disprove this.

Comment: You presumably assumed $f\in C^1[a,b]$. Then the norm $||\cdot||_2$ is smaller or equal to $||\cdot||_1$. For the other inequality, we can use the fundamental theorem of analysis or the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, obviously $$
  \|f\|_2 \leq \|f\|_1
$$
because $|f(a)| \leq \|f\|_\infty$ by definition of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. So the question is, is there a $C$ such that $$
  \|f\|_1 \leq C\cdot \|f\|_2 \text{.}
$$
To prove that, it suffices to show that there's a $C' > 0$ with $$
  \|f\|_\infty \leq  |f(a)| + C'\|f'\|_\infty \quad(\star)
$$
because then (for $C = C'+1 > 1$)$$
  \|f\|_1 = \|f\|_\infty + \|f'\|_\infty
  \leq \underbrace{|f(a)|}_{\leq C|f(a)|} + \underbrace{C'\|f'\|_\infty + \|f'\|_\infty}_{=C\|f'\|_\infty}
  \leq C|f(a)| + C\|f'\|_\infty
   = C\|f\|_2 \text{.}
$$

So what's left is to prove $(\star)$. For that, you can either use the fundamental theorem of calculus, or the intermediate value theorem.